# Tengo un problema con una operacion en c++

Tags: c++

**Solicitar matricula ,calificaciones 1 ,2 y 3 e imprimir el promedio y matricula **
Es lo que se me pide, el problema radica en que me sale error al momento de intentar dividir el resultado de las calificaciones.(si detectas un problema con lo demás seria un gusto que me lo corrijas)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int calif1, calif2, calif3,matricula[7], promedio;
  cout << "ingrese matricula:" << endl;
  cin >> matricula[7];
  cout<<"ingrese calificaciones 1" << endl;
  cin >> calif1;
  cout << "ingrese calificaciones 2" << endl;
  cin >> calif2;
  cout << "ingrese calificaciones 3" << endl;
  cin >> calif3;
  
  promedio << (calif1 + calif2 + calif3) /3 << endl;//(operacion:)
  cout << "La matricula es:" << matricula[7] << " y promedio de:" << promedio << endl;  //impresion
  system ("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A la hora de calcular el promedio utilizas el operador `<<` que se utiliza para enviar información a un flujo de salida y eso es incorrecto en este caso porque lo que buscas solamente es asignar un valor a la variable promedio, en su lugar deberías usar el operador de asignación (=):

```
int main()
{
  int calif1, calif2, calif3,matricula[7], promedio;
  cout << "ingrese matricula:" << endl;
  cin >> matricula[7];
  cout<<"ingrese calificaciones 1" << endl;
  cin >> calif1;
  cout << "ingrese calificaciones 2" << endl;
  cin >> calif2;
  cout << "ingrese calificaciones 3" << endl;
  cin >> calif3;
  
  promedio = (calif1 + calif2 + calif3) / 3; //(operacion:)
  cout << "La matricula es:" << matricula[7] << " y promedio de:" << promedio << endl;  //impresion  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mira amigo,no entiendo por que metes la matricula con un array de 7 , y encima le das valor al espacio 7 que no existe, ya q lo creastes de 0-6 (serian 7), pero ya te digo puedes dejarlo como int.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int calif1, calif2, calif3,matricula, promedio;// no hace falta q sea array
  cout << "ingrese matricula:" << endl;
  cin >> matricula;
  cout<<"ingrese calificaciones 1" << endl;
  cin >> calif1;
  cout << "ingrese calificaciones 2" << endl;
  cin >> calif2;
  cout << "ingrese calificaciones 3" << endl;
  cin >> calif3;
  
  promedio = (calif1 + calif2 + calif3) / 3; 
  cout << "La matricula es:" << matricula << " y promedio de:" << promedio << endl;  //impresion  
}
```